# retrieving name from number ID

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text, python-3.x

I have a code that takes data from online where items are referred to by a number ID, compared data about those items, and builds a list of item ID numbers based on some criteria. What I'm struggling with is taking this list of numbers and turning it into a list of names. I have a text file with the numbers and corresponding names but am having trouble using it because it contains multi-word names and retains the \n at the end of each line when i try to parse the file in any way with python. the text file looks like this:

```
number    name\n
14        apple\n
27        anjou pear\n
36        asian pear\n
7645      langsat\n
```

I have tried split(), as well as replacing the white space between with several difference things to no avail. I asked a question earlier which yielded a lot of progress but still didn't quite work. The two methods that were suggested were:

```
d = dict()
f=open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    number, name = line.split(None,1)
    d[number] = name
```

this almost worked but still left me with the \n so if I call `d['14']` i get `'apple\n'`. The other method was:

```
import re
f=open('file.txt', 'r')
fr=f.read()
r=re.findall("(\w+)\s+(.+)", fr)
```

this seemed to have gotten rid of the `\n` at the end of every name but leaves me with the problem of having a tuple with each number-name combo being a single entry so if i were to say `r[1]` i would get `('14', 'apple')`. I really don't want to delete each new line command by hand on all ~8400 entries...

Any recommendations on how to get the corresponding name given a number from a file like this?

Comment: try: `number, name = line.strip().split(None,1)`... works as your code, but in addition `strip()` will drop the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first method change the line `ttn[number] = name` to `ttn[number] = name[:-1]`. This simply strips off the last character, and should remove your `\n`.

Comment: `'any_text\n'.rstrip()` would do the same, removing other right whitespace as well

Comment: As others have suggested, strip or rstrip is probably a better solution. With mine, you'll lose the last letter of the last name if the last line in the file doesn't have a newline, and it won't remove any trailing whitespace if there is any before the \n.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = {}

with open("id_file.txt") as inf:
    header = next(inf, '')  # skip header row
    for line in inf:
        id, name = line.split(None, 1)
        names[int(id)] = name.strip()

names[27]    # => 'anjou pear'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to modify your first approach:

```
raw_dict = dict()
cleaned_dict = dict()
```

Assuming you've imported file to dictionary:

```
raw_dict = {14:"apple\n",27:"anjou pear\n",36 :"asian pear\n" ,7645:"langsat\n"}


for keys in raw_dict:
    cleaned_dict[keys] = raw_dict[keys][:len(raw_dict[keys])-1]
```

So now, cleaned_dict is equal to:

```
{27: 'anjou pear', 36: 'asian pear', 7645: 'langsat', 14: 'apple'}
```

*Edited to add first sentence.